# Android Studio does not recognice org.apache.cordova.* in activity using gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-studio, cordova-4

My goal for this "project" was to have a running development environment for cordova in Android Studio using gradle, which i archived so far.
Only Problem being that Android Studio does not seem to recognize Cordova even tough building & emulating works fine.

This is what i did to come to the Situation I am in right now:

Using a Checkout of [`Cordova 4`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/4.0.x) I created a new application :

```
./cordova-android/bin/create CordovaTestThree com.acme.CordovaTestThree CordovaTestThree
```

After that i build the application using gradle:

```
cd CordovaTestThree
./cordova/build --gradle
```

The next step was to import the project in to [`Android Studio 0.8.6`](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) via `File > Import Project >`.

There where some errors/warnings in the `CordovaTestThree/build.gradle` and `CordovaTestThree/CordovaLib/build.gradle` in regards to `buildscript > dependencies >classpath` which i changed to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0` and `android > buildToolsVersion` which in my case i changed to `19.1.0` .

After which I can successfully build, run and test the application but I am seeing errors in the IDE, see screen:

[image]
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdVv9.jpg)